I need the address of the oracle service that provides football match results and related pricing information
I am a blockchain developer, and I am currently working on a football betting project. I have completed the development of the relevant contracts on Ethereum. Now, I need an oracle service that provides football match results. However, I cannot find such a service on the Chainlink official website. Where can I get this service and related pricing information, or who has experience using it that can share?

You can use Chainlink Functions, and consume any available Football API.
You can explore some of the available Football APIs from this list.
First, you can follow Chainlink Functions Getting Started Guide and see how the contract is consuming this API endpoint (https://swapi.info/api/people/${characterId}/) and getting the desired data in the response.
So, you can potentially modify that contract to consume your desired Football API and return the corresponding result.
But, if you want to build something faster by consuming some existing Sports Data Oracle or so, then you can get in touch with LinkWell Nodes as they are one of the most reputed Chainlink node operators out there, and can potentially provide you  with the best quality real-time data on-chain real quick.
